Need to export the output of powershell script of to csv file
I have script to get the count of a Security group from active directory. But i need to export those output to csv file. In csv file i  need input data in one column and output will be in next column.
Here the script
$Groups = Get-Content D:\group1.txt
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
$ADInfo = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Group -Properties Members
$AdInfo.Members.Count 
}

Current output
.

You want only the count? Not the associated group name?

I want the count and associated group name as well

does this answer your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.4

You can use the Export-Csv cmdlet to export data to a CSV file. It'll create 1 row per object you pipe to it, so all you need to do is construct objects with the group name and the count as property values:
# read group names from file
$groupNames = Get-Content D:\group1.txt 

# fetch the group members
$groupsWithMembers = $groupNames |Get-ADGroup -Properties Members 

# create 1 new object per group, containing 2 properties - Name and Count
$groupMemberCounts = $groupsWithMembers |Select-Object Name,@{Name='Count';Expression={$_.Members.Count}}

# export to CSV
$groupMemberCounts |Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation

You could also compose a single pipeline that does all 4 steps:
Get-Content D:\group1.txt |Get-ADGroup -Properties Members |Select-Object Name,@{Name='Count';Expression={$_.Members.Count}} |Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation


Thanks, now i got the output as what i expected
